# icpc: command line error: option '-openmp' not supported

Tags: c++, openmp, icc

I am trying to compile simple code using openmp.

Here is the code (file test.cpp):

```
int main()
{
    double a[100];
    #pragma omp parallel for
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
        a[i] = i;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I compile using the following command:

```
icpc -openmp test.cpp
```

the result is:

```
icpc: command line error: option '-openmp' not supported
```

OS Debian X64

Can you help me please?

**Update:**

using -fopenmp gives the same error.

From here: https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/522690

Command-Line Examples, Linux*
To compile and link (build) the entire application with one command using the Intel OpenMP libraries, specify the following Intel® C++ Compiler command on Linux* platforms:

C source

icc -openmp hello.c

C++ source

icpc -openmp hello.cpp

**UPDATE2:**

-qopenmp gives the same error.
I installed intel system studio, and use the compiler from /opt/intel/bin. In PATH there is nothing related to intel. Maybe i should add somethin to PATH for intel to recognize that it can use openmp. I have tried only adding to PATH /opt/intel/bin.

Comment: See my updated answer.

Comment: Are you by any chance using the cross-compiler that targets embedded hardware?

Answer (score 2):

`-openmp` used to be the option for enabling the OpenMP support in older versions of the Intel compiler. In the newer versions the option is `-qopenmp`.

In any case, even the newest version (17.0) accepts `-openmp`:

```
$ icpc -openmp test.cpp
icpc: command line remark #10411: option '-openmp' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use the replacement option '-qopenmp'
```

Therefore, there is probably something wrong with the setup of your Intel compilers. As a hint, Intel compilers tend to issue error numbers for unrecognised options. Make sure that `icpc` is indeed the Intel compiler and not a wrapper around GCC or an alias.

Answer (score 0):

How about

`-qopenmp`

I think that's the official way you add OpenMP to intel compiler.

If you're on Windows, then use:

`/Qopenmp`

Comment: `-fopenmp` has never been recognised by the Intel compiler. The option used to be `-openmp` and in recent versions was replaced by `-qopenmp`.